# How to explain instrumental variables to your friends?

Tags: intuition, instrumental-variables

Is there an even simpler way of explaining IV than described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190316/how-to-explain-instrumental-variables-to-a-layman)? I was recently talking to my friend about my research and was wondering how to convey the intuition of instrumental variables to someone that hasn't even taken a statistics course. This might be too much to ask, but would be curious to see if any of you have encountered this issue and how you went about this.

Thanks everyone, super curious!

P.S.: I mostly just avoid talking about the IV part of my work of course, but sometimes people come up with all kinds of alternative explanations and aren't satisfied with me telling them that I am doing as much statistical work as I can to approximate causal results.

Comment: There are also explanations here: [What is an instrumental variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/563/), & here: [What do “endogeneity” and “exogeneity” mean substantively?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59588/)

Comment: The [DAG](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/333488/7071) or an RCT with imperfect one-sided compliance/Wald estimator usually gets the intuition across.

Comment: Also at https://towardsdatascience.com/instrumental-variables-a-practical-explanation-1a583408a5b9